# Renaming Handle in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-16

I am new to odoo, I have managed to customize the application to some extend but I am trying to either remove, disable or rename the handle in Odoo under user - preference - notification. see attached image.

is this possible? I just don't want users to see that option.

Thank you for your help.

[handle in Odoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY1Zd.jpg)

I tried to edit it under the notification field but it returns error that I can't edit the field.
see attached images

[Notification type field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWsy3.png)
[Error trying to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f69kr.png)

Comment: You have all the source code.  Have you searched for that string?

Comment: Thank you Tim, I figured it out. I just needed to edit it under field selection.